# Excel: How to evaluate arrays of boolean in SUMPRODUCT?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Take the following table. If I want to do SUMPRODUCT with a condition,

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5,--($C$1:$C$5="b"))
```

gives the correct answer 38 (cell A7). I understand --() is converting booleans to 1s and 0s.

Q1

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5,IF($C$1:$C$5="b",1,0))
```

gives #VALUE (cell A8). But when I check the arguments, excel shows the 3rd argument is successfully evaluated as 1s and 0s. So what went wrong such that #VALUE is shown?
[image]

Q2

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5,$C$1:$C$5="b")
```

is evaluated as 0 (cell A9). This means that Excel treats all booleans as 0s if you don't convert them to numbers. Is there any specific reason for this?

Q3 Other than using --() (because at first, this does not look intuitive to me), is there any other way to convert an array of booleans to 1s and 0s? More specifically, any functions so that the formula would look easier to understand?

Comment: with the second if you confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode it will work.  The third returns text TRUE/FALSE and when the sumproduct tries to multiply to a text it will error and skip that iteration, so it will return `0` as it returns only errors.

Comment: If it is easier to understand you can do `($C$1:$C$5="b")+0` or `($C$1:$C$5="b")*1` or `VALUE($C$1:$C$5="b")`  any will turn the TRUE/FALSE into 1/0.

Comment: Or you can use only two arrays: `=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5*($C$1:$C$5="b"))` and combine the second and the third with `*`

Comment: sorry, the `Value` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5,IF($C$1:$C$5="b",1,0)) formula is OK, but you must enter it as  array (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)